# How to get data of a variable from one class into another class in python?

Tags: python-3.x, class

so I am writing code where I generate certain data in a class and save it in a dictionary. I want to use that data in the second class . The first class is as fellows:

```
class DataAnalysis():

    def __init__(self,matfile=None):
        '''Constructor
        '''
        self.matfile= matfile
    def get_alldata(self):
        print('all dict data accessed')
        print(bodedata_dict)
        return bodedata_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj1= DataAnalysis(matfile=matfile)
    "do some work"
    bodedata_dict.update(bode_data)
    obj1.get_alldata()
```

I then access the dictionary in the second class as:

```
from A import DataAnalysis

class PlotComaparison(DataAnalysis):
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj= DataAnalysis(matfile=None)
    obj1= PlotComaparison(obj)
    dict_data= obj.get_alldata()
```

But when I run the script with the second class, it gives me the following error:
File "DataAnalysis.py", line 301, in get_alldata
print(bodedata_dict)
NameError: name 'bodedata_dict' is not defined

I am very new to the concept of classes in python, so please help me with how I can use data from one class into another.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_alldata()` method in the `DataAnalysis` class you defined is returning a `bodedata_dict` which isn't defined anywhere. It's like printing the content of a variable without defining it first.

EDIT:
Looking further into it, `bodedata_dict`in the first example comes from outside the class. You would likely want to change the flow of your program so that when `DataAnalysis` has it's get data method called, it doesn't depend on an outside state.

Comment: but get_alldata() function works fine in the DataAnalysis class.. When I try calling it in the other class, it gives that error

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by it working fine in the DataAnalysis class?
If you mean that it compiles creating the class, then it would work. As when a class or a function is being defined, it does't check if the variables used troughout the definition are valid or defined. Still, ask yourself this: what is `bodedata_dict` supposed to be and where does it come from?

Comment: bodedata_dict is a dictionary that is being generated in the main method of DataAnalysis class.

Comment: If you mean the `if __name__ == '__main__':` method. It doesn't run when you import files. You should change it so that the bodedata_dict is somehow created and stored inside the class